# mac os x - usb hid - how the receive device added / device removed callbacks?

Tags: macos, hid

I'm a beginner at programming on mac os x.

I am following this [tutorial](http://ontrak.net/xcode.htm).

And I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h>
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDKeys.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

static void Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback(void *inContext, IOReturn inResult, void *inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef)
{
    puts("YAY Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback");
}

static void Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback(void *inContext, IOReturn inResult, void *inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef)
{
    puts("YAY Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback");
}

int main()
{
    IOHIDManagerRef HIDManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(HIDManager, NULL);

    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(HIDManager, &Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback, NULL);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(HIDManager, &Handle_DeviceRemovalCallback, NULL);

    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(HIDManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    IOReturn IOReturn = IOHIDManagerOpen(HIDManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    if(IOReturn) puts("IOHIDManagerOpen failed.");

    while(1)
    {
        puts("sleeping...");
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I am doing wrong, because I do not get the callbacks when I insert or remove any hid device in the USB port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop` is hooked to **Run Loop**, so You need to start one. `while` loop is not the solution here. So in order to get callbacks, You should replace `while` loop with `CFRunLoopRun()` call.

More informations about RunLoops in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16).

Comment: can you tell me please how do I break out from that loop when I'm done using my program? I’ve tried the following, in main
    CFRunLoopRun();
    CFRunLoopRef run_loop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
and when I want to exit I call:
CFRunLoopStop(run_loop);
but run_loop is NULL.

Comment: You need to call this code in a callback, since this method does not return immediately. So You can create new callback for an event (timer, etc.) and call `CFRunLoopStop()` there, or remove all sources an timers from the RunLoop to make it stop.